# Effect of X-rays on UV curing resin

Tags: material-science, x-rays

What happens when 3d printer resin is exposed to x-ray radiation?

From my (very) limited understanding, UV rays are packets of a high enough energy to cause the resin to change from a liquid into a solid.
Therefore, X-rays being of higher energy (even if they need to be a harmonic of the specific UV radiation) should also cure the resin. However, X-rays would also penetrate further, solidifying the entire container of resin, rather than just the surface layer.

Thanks for your help!